# Calling WebAPI from a scheduled job using quartz.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, quartz.net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a nightly job run setup with quartz.net this all works fine but when I get to the part where I call ± 15 WebAPI's to consume them and publish the results in JSON files via FTP to the server i get into trouble.

The WebAPI's don't fire I think perhaps this is because the wrong user does this? but I am not sure.

What could be my problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: As it stands, this question seems odd. Web APIs normally don't "fire". You have to query them.

Comment: Could you provide us some code?